# Open bootstrap 4.5 modal with a custom url in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

So my goal is to launch bootstrap (v4.5) modal when the user open URL with ID at the end (ex: www.site.com/event/newyear/#termsandconditions)

I've found several tutorials about this, and nothing is working for my **Wordpress** site.

So here's the code for the button:

```
<a href="#exampleModal" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
Launch demo modal
</a>
```

And here's the code for the modal:

```
<div id="exampleModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
        ...
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
     </div>
  </div>
```

I insert JS at the end, before the closing /body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  if(window.location.href.indexOf('#exampleModal') != -1) {
    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
  }

});
</script>
```

Somebody please tell me what I've missed.

Comment: `href="/event/newyear/#exampleModal"` have you tried this?

Comment: Hi @Fresz thanks for the comment, but it wasn't the button that going to be a problem. I clicked the button and the modal is working (it's pop up). The problem is within the URL, I want to open the modal without clicking the modal button, just enter the URL like this: www.site.com/event/newyear/#termsandconditions and i want the modal auto opened

Comment: Have you succeed? I need to know too.